# Mongo Schema With Ref: Document Not Updating With Save

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a blog and I'm trying to add the ability for a user to add a comment to the blog.  I've created a `comment` model with reference to my `blog` model.  When I try to add a comment to a `blog` in Postman, it is saving the `comment` in the comment document, but not adding the associated `comment` to my `blog` document.  I want the blog items in my document to have their own comments field, with each individual comment.

**Comment Model**

```
const commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  comment: { type: String, required: true },
  blog: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Blog"
  }
});

commentSchema.set("toJSON", {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString();
    delete returnedObject._id;
    delete returnedObject.__v;
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

**Blog Model**

```
const blogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: String, required: true },
  url: String,
  likes: Number,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  comments: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Comment"
  }
});

blogSchema.set("toJSON", {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString();
    delete returnedObject._id;
    delete returnedObject.__v;
  }
});
```

**My Express Code where I'm trying to add a new comment**

```
blogsRouter.post("/:id/comments", async (request, response, next) => {
  try {
    const blog = await Blog.findById(request.params.id);
    console.log("Blog", blog);
    const comment = new Comment({
      comment: request.body.comment,
      blog: blog._id
    });
    const result = await comment.save();
    console.log("Blog Comments", blog.comments);
    blog.comments = blog.comments.concat(result._id);
    await blog.save();
    response.status(201).json(result.toJSON());
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

The above code when submitting to that route in Postman results in the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
```

[image]

as shown below, the comment is coming through fine, and saving to the database in the Comments document but isn't populating the Blog document, thus I think why I'm getting this error?

Note I am populating the user and the comments in my Get and Put routes for the blog.  I can post if needed, maybe there is a problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to build one-to-many relationship between `blogSchema` and `commentSchema`. This would mean that you need to modify `comments` in your `blogSchema`:

```
const blogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    author: { type: String, required: true },
    url: String,
    likes: Number,
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ]
});
```

This will allow you to use `concat` or `push` like below:

```
blog.comments.push(comment);
```

Outcome should be the same